# Trouble with Forking Process and Calling bc using execve

Tags: c, linux, fork, bc, execve

my program is meant to fork a process, read from a file line by line within the parent and shove these lines down a pipe to be passed to bc which is called using execve.

The file I am using is a text file that simply contains 5 + 10.

Parent process reads 'em in like this:

```
while(fgets(newWord, sizeof newWord, coolFile) != NULL)
{
    write(stdin_pipe_fds[1], newWord, (strlen(newWord)+1));
}
```

Child calls bc like this:

```
execve("/usr/bin/bc", argv, NULL);
```

Running the program gives me this error message:

```
 scg3q@system64:~/CS/project4$ (standard_in) 1: syntax error
 (standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^@
 (standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

This happens when I try to execve bc. Any ideas?

EDIT: making sure the null terminator is not passed to bc via the pipe fixes one error message(Illegal character), but the other two remain. Hoping someone has an idea of the problem could be!

Answer (score 2):

Don't add 1 to `strlen(newWord)`. That's causing you to write the null terminator to the pipe, but `bc` doesn't expect a null byte in its input.

```
write(stdin_pipe_fds[1], newWord, (strlen(newWord)));
```

To fix the other syntax error, make sure that `newWord` ends with a newline character, because `bc` requires its input to be complete lines.

Comment: Well, that got rid of the illegal character message, but the other two remain.

Comment: Do you have a newline at the end of `newWord`? `bc` requires the input to end with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

> Running the program gives me this error message:
>
> ```
> scg3q@system64:~/CS/project4$ (standard_in) 1: syntax error
> (standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^@
> (standard_in) 1: syntax error
> ```

Those messages are from `bc`.  They are complaining that the data you are feeding to its standard input are syntactically incorrect on account of an illegal character, ^@, which is the null terminator that you are erroneously careful to send down the stream.  That's not part of the input you read, and it should not be sent to `bc`.

Comment: Yes,thank you, making sure the null terminator is not sent down the pipe fixes the illegal character message, but the other two remain. Any ideas?

Comment: @OldIslander, nothing else presented in the question explains any errors, but it is suspicious that you are passing the program's argument vector (`argv`) on to `bc` as its own.  Alternatively, the issue might be something in the input file, so try feeding that directly to `bc`, via a command along the lines of `bc <my_input_file`.